# I am new to android development and I have a problem in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
public class Memo extends AppCompatActivity {
DBHandler dbh;
Notes items;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_memo);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    try{
        dbh = new DBHandler(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
   display();
}

public void display( ){              //method to display all items in the database
    List<Notes> books_list = dbh.getNotes();             ////here i get the list fromm the database
    ///// i used a custom adapter because i needed it
    final myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, books_list);          ///creating adapter from 
myadapter to link it with  the list
    ListView _note_ = findViewById(R.id.list_txt);
    _note_.setAdapter(adapter);

    _note_.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {     //// 
when clicking on item the hidden fields will be visible
            items = (Notes) adapter.getItem(position);
            String Note_content = items.getNote();
            String title = items.getTitle();
            String Date = items.getDate();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,Note_content.class);
            i.putExtra("Note ", Note_content);
            i.putExtra("title", title);
            i.putExtra("Date", Date);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    _note_.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            items = (Notes) adapter.getItem(position);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Memo.this);
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Memo.this);
            View m1View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.update_custom, null);
            final EditText txt_Date1 = (EditText) m1View.findViewById(R.id.txt_custom1_Date);
            final EditText txt_title1 = (EditText) m1View.findViewById(R.id.txt_custom1_title);
            final EditText txt_note1 = (EditText) m1View.findViewById( R.id.txt_note1);
            final Button btn_cancel = (Button) m1View.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel1);
            final Button btn_okay = (Button) m1View.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok1);
            alert.setView(m1View);
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            builder.setNegativeButton("delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dbh.deleteNote(items);
                    display();
                    Toast.makeText(Memo.this, "item has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    btn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            final String ttitle = txt_title1.getText().toString();
                            final String nnote = txt_note1.getText().toString();
                            final String dDate = txt_Date1.getText().toString();
                                Notes Ttnote = new Notes(ttitle, nnote, dDate);
                                dbh.updatenotes(Ttnote);
                                display();
                                //Toast.makeText(Memo.this, "item has been updated" + items.getId() + 
" " + ttitle+ " " + nnote, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            alertDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

                    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
            });
            builder.setTitle("Choose Option");

            builder.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I want to update the note and when I use Toast to show the ttilte ,nnote and Ddate they are correct but they are not updating in the list
and here is the method I use to update in DBHandler I cant find any error in the code and when i run it it works without any errors but i cant get the updated note in the list

```
public void updatenotes (Notes note){        //method to update
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         /// getting the values
    values.put(" title" , note.getTitle());
    values.put("note" ,note.getNote());
    values.put("date", note.getDate());

    db.update(TABLE_NAME_notes, values ,"id=?" ,new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())} ); 
///perform the updating query
db.close();



}
```

Comment: Please use a different subject. The subject should tell which problem you have. And if you do not have a problem with Android Studio itself then remove that tag.

Comment: can you please add the Table schema as well.

Comment: remove the space in title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Notes Ttnote = new Notes(ttitle, nnote, dDate);
                                dbh.updatenotes(Ttnote);
```

You are creating new Object of Note everytime on button click and trying to update the older one in database.

try this

```
final String ttitle = txt_title1.getText().toString();
                            final String nnote = txt_note1.getText().toString();
                            final String dDate = txt_Date1.getText().toString();

items.setTitle(ttitle);
items.setnote(nnote);
items.setDate(dDate);
```

update in database

fetch the list again and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: dbh.updatenotes(Ttnote);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                display();  this is the code but nothing changed

Comment: @muaazDeyab, after deleting, fetch a new list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: it works , I used items to update notes 
dbh.updatenotes(items);
it workd without adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
 thank you so much